# Get comma separated values when trying to call a soap web service

Tags: web-services, soap, plsql, oracle-apex

I tried to call a soap web service in my package and its response is in this way..

```
    <tns:abcdef>
      <ns2:name>anji</ns2:name>
    </tns:abcdef>
    <tns:abcdef>
      <ns2:name>Reddy</ns2:name>
    </tns:abcdef>
```

I'm storing the result of the node in a variable and its getting stored as anjireddy.

But I need the response as anji,reddy how can I achieve that?

Comment: "I'm storing the result of the node in a variable" - how are you doing that now? Please edit your question to show your current code, and maybe explain a bit more?

Comment: sur_name :=
            apex_web_service.parse_xml
                                 (p_xml        => l_xml,
                                  p_xpath      => '//name/text()',
                                   p_ns => 'xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/abv/svg/xsd/v1/surlist"'
                                 );

Comment: This is how I'm doing it just storing the response given by that specific node in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are calling only seems to support XPath 1.0, or a subset of it; it doesn't like `string-join()` or even simple FLWOR expressions.

In case no-one who knows APEX comes up with a sensibel solution, you ca work around it by parsing the XML manually, instead of calling `parse_xml()`:

```
select xmlquery('string-join(//*:name/text(), ",")'
  passing l_xml returning content).getstringval()
into sur_name
from dual;
```

I've been lazy and wild-carded the namespace, but you can include proper namespace clauses to make it more correct and robust.

As a demo in an anonymous block:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  sur_name varchar2(230);
  l_xml xmltype := xmltype('<root xmlns:tns="abcdef.com/abv/svg/xsd/v1/surlis" xmlns:ns2="abcdef.com/abv/svg/xsd/v1/surlist">
    <tns:abcdef>
      <ns2:name>anji</ns2:name>
    </tns:abcdef>
    <tns:abcdef>
      <ns2:name>Reddy</ns2:name>
    </tns:abcdef>
</root>');
begin
  select xmlquery('string-join(//*:name/text(), ",")'
    passing l_xml returning content).getstringval()
  into sur_name
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(sur_name);
end;
/

anji,Reddy


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I can't really use the select statement here, I just need to get the response from web service in such a way that it seperates the data with commas.